# Доступ к микрофону в WebView

Tags: android, webview

Создаю `WebView` и передаю ей ссылку на ресурс.

```
web = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.web);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.loadUrl("http...");
```

При переходе по URL осуществляется попытка получить доступ к микрофону но, `WebView` блокирует эту попытку. Вопрос, как мне дать разрешение на использование микрофона для `web`?

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите разрешение в `Manifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT"/>
```

Если Вы используете Android 6.0 и выше, придется запросит разрешение в процессе выполнения. Подробнее об этом тут — [официальный сайт](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Увы, не помогло

Comment: @Heaven, а что пишет-то?

Comment: "Доступ к микрофону запрещен. Проверьте настройки браузера"

Comment: Но при этом есть кнопка которая ведет на данный url и есть нажать эту кнопку(то есть осуществить явный переход) всё проходит успешно